# What would be the XPATH for XML with condition

Tags: jmeter

Have the following XML response,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<globalTestList rowCount="1">
    <testcase>
        <checkedOut>N</checkedOut>
        <group name="PerfTest105" recid="2489"/>
        <testImportance>0</testImportance>
        <testRecid>2491</testRecid>
        <testType>Conventional Function Test</testType>
        <preFetched>Y</preFetched>
        <priority>6</priority>
        <series>Functional</series>
        <test id="98132" recid="2401"/>
        <subject number="98132" recid="2476"/>
        <testCode>555210</testCode>
        <userId>1201</userId>
        <test name="Functional Test 1" recid="2478"/>
        <workflowChangeDate>2023-06-28T13:07:08Z</workflowChangeDate>
        <workflowState>Testing.Imported</workflowState>
    </testcase>
</globalTestList>
```

What to retrieve the `recid` from `<group name="PerfTest105" recid="2489"/>`. Specifically it should be associated group attribute which is  `2489` as there are other `recid` as well.

Know values from previous response are,

know from previous response `recid="2478"` and `recid="2401"` & `555210`.

Is there a way using xpath/ regex I can fetch the `recid` for the `group`. also cannot trust `group name="PerfTest105"` as it is dynamic too.

I tried with `//timsCode[text()='555210']/parent::*/@recid` but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost solved it,

your xapth should be `//testCode[text()='555210']/parent::*/group/@recid`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest going the other direction, in this case you will be able to avoid [selection of all nodes](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) followed by filtering and doing it twice when you're matching the parent.

The following XPath expression should work for you:

```
/globalTestList/testcase[testCode='555210']/group/@recid
```

More information:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/xpath-extractor-jmeter)

Using regular expression extractor for getting data from non-regular languages is [not the best idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748).